# Opposite of adjacent sibling selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Please check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vfMsS/. I need to write selectors which select the element after the "active" element and the element before it. The "before" part doesn't seem to work. How to select the element before the `a.active`?

Comment: In currently supported CSS, it's not possible to select backwards or upwards. You can only select forwards and downwards. Selecting backwards or upwards requires JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Or, a `float: right` after reversing the layout of the elements via HTML.  Read my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 7):

Like BoltClock said, there is no way to due this in current day browsers. 
However, I believe it is possible in CSS.

The [CSS Selectors level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) syntax (specifically see [this](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject)) with the syntax `E! + F` for "An element E preceding an element F".

So in your case the syntax would be `a! + a.active` meaning "An element with tag a preceding an element with tag a and class active". As of today, this is [not yet implemented in any layout engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#Selectors)

Comment: And to apply the same rule to elements that come before and after, use `a! + a.active, a.active + a`.

Comment: I guess this has been removed from the draft.
CSS is cascading...!

Comment: The replacement (not implemented anywhere yet) will be `a:not(:has(+ a.active))` Here are the [mozilla docs for `:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), the [mozilla docs for `:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) (which includes a browser support table) and the [CSS4 draft for `:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational).

Answer (score 6):

The adjacent sibling selector only looks forward, not backward. There is no `-` combinator for previous adjacent siblings.

If you simply need to select anything that isn't `.active` in the same parent, and you don't mind slightly reduced browser support, you can use `:not()` instead. If you need to specify a different style for the one that comes after `.active`, you need to override:

```
a:not(.active) { background:red }
a.active + a { background:yellow }
```

Again, this assumes they always share the same parent.

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vfMsS/7)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same solution of targeting the elements behind the `.active`link

I set a default style for any element before the one `.active` then I selected all after that one with the sibling selector.

`a.active { background: #ccc;}
a.active ~ * { background: yellow }
a { background: red }`

Demo: https://codepen.io/ramiro-ruiz/pen/gBOPQL

That worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using a sibling combinator?

```
a.active ~ a { background:red }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/6x7d9vm7/

Comment: because even in your example that does exactly the same as +

Comment: this can work only if you know there are going to be well defined items in the same 'level' of your document.  for instance if you have an `h1` and an `h2` and you know there will only be 0 or 1 of them then this can work well`

Comment: Answer by Vixed doesn't work (even in the example provided).
Answer by Simon_Weaver works only in specific case when there is next sibling after the node with class .active. If there is no next sibling, the whole thing stops working, so the answer is also wrong. The only correct answer is: This can't be done in CSS at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, this is an issue I had for a while, and one of the things I didn't like much ended up resolving this issue... `float: right`.

In my case, it was the `input[type='radio'] + label` element, and since CSS flows forward and not backwards, `~ input[type='radio'] + label` would choose all the siblings after the element that was checked.

Since, `float: right` is responsible for taking "A, B, C" and positioning them as "C, B, A" - I changed the order of radio elements from 1-6 to 6-1 in the HTML, and made them `float: right` with CSS.

What this did was reverse them back into the order of 1-6 when rendered to the browser.

Now, when I used `~ input[type='radio'] + label`, it still defined the styles the same way (which in my case, was the color of the label), however, the siblings being styled were now - visually - the preceding ones.

This thread is over a year old, but if anyone needs an example, I'll create and post a pen if asked.