# Make required fields appear red using css3 and jquery.validate

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make required fields in a form to appear red, but am not have any luck.
Below is my form and the css I have tried.

contact.html

```
                        <h2>Send us an email...</h2>
                        <br/>
                        <ul>

                            <li>
                                <label for="senderName"  >Your Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" required="required" placeholder="Please type your name"   maxlength="40" />
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <label for="senderEmail" >Your Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" required="required"  placeholder="Please type your email address"   maxlength="50" />
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <label for="message" style="padding-top: .5em;" >Your Message</label>
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Please type your message" required="required" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <div id="formButtons">
                            <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Send Email" />
                            <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

style.css

```
label[required=required]{
    color: darkred;
}

label[] > input[required="required"] {
    background: red;  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `<input>` element has the required attribute and appears after the `<label>`, you would want an previous sibling selector, which unfortunately does not exist in CSS. You cannot select *backwards* in CSS, only forwards.

You could use the `+` selector but it would require re-arranging your HTML so that the `<label>` is after the `<input>`, Once you do this, this would work:

```
input[required]+label {
    background: red;
}
```

If this is not desirable, you would need to give the label a class of its own which you can use, like `<label class="required">...</label>`.

See this related question: [Opposite of adjacent sibling selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449622/opposite-of-adjacent-sibling-selector)

Comment: That works but it throws off the layout of the form. The label now appears under the input vs in front of it

Comment: Yes if that is unacceptable then you would need to give the label a class, for example "required" and just do `label.required { background:red; }`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a way can give the label the required attribute and select it using that attribute.

Comment: Never mind I figured that out, using `label[required]{ background-color: red; }`